# list_display doesn't work

Tags: python, django

There is a class named `Employees` in `models.py`

```
class Employees(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.CharField(verbose_name = _("Employee ID"), max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    employee_name = models.CharField(verbose_name = _("Employee Name"), max_length=20)
    department = models.CharField(verbose_name = _("Department"), max_length=100)
    post = models.CharField(verbose_name = _("Post"), max_length=100)
```

Then I wrote some code in `admin.py`

```
class EmployeesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('employee_id', 'employee_name', 'department', 'post')
```

According to the tutorial, there should be four fields in the Employee branch. But in my situation, there is only one field named `Employees`, just like I didn't add `EmployeesAdmin` class in `admin.py`. What's wrong with it? Did I miss something?

---

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Employees, Purchase, ProductsOut

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Employees)
admin.site.register(Purchase)
admin.site.register(ProductsOut)
```

Comment: can you show us your  `admin.py`?

Comment: @Michael, updated, I have another two classes written in `models.py` file, but I think this is not a problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Register your admin in admin.site like:-

```
admin.site.register(ModelName, AdminName)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following after declaring your `EmployeesAdmin` class in admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(Employees, EmployeesAdmin)
```